# Customizing filter drop down in data view in Sharepoint Designer

Tags: xml, sharepoint, filter, sharepoint-designer, dataviewwebpart

I have a dataviewwebpart with filtering, sorting and grouping enabled for a list, done using SharePoint designer. The list has some category columns that are used in filter dropdowns appearing as a toolbar above the data view when deployed. How can I remove them from the dropdown?

I googled on this and found that dvt.filterfield is what populates the filter dropdowns.
Currently, my dataview is as follows:

Filter       Sort by dropdown    Group by dropdown

List...

When I click on filter all the columns currently in the list appear as filter options. Repeating my question, I want to remove 2-3 columns from the options displayed. How do I do that?

Hope this question is clear. I'll post a screenshot of the site if anybody needs it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found just the link I wanted. Here(if anybody does wanna know):
[Advanced DVWB sorting and filtering](http://blogs.catapultsystems.com/tlingenfelder/archive/2009/07/29/advanced-data-view-web-part-sorting-grouping-and-filtering.aspx)